# Properly Format a datetime-local form input via echo from MYSQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to echo the value of arrivalDateTimeDest into a form so that the user can edit this value. I've attempted to accomplish this a few ways, however, the value that's echo's always equals mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --. What am I doing wrong? My attempts are listed below.

```
<input type='datetime-local' id="arrivalDateTimeDest" name='arrivalDateTimeDest' value="<?php echo date_format($row['arrivalDateTimeDest'],'Y/m/d H:i:s')?>">

<input type='datetime-local' id="arrivalDateTimeDest" name='arrivalDateTimeDest' value="<?php echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $row['arrivalDateTimeDest'])?>">

<input type='datetime-local' id="arrivalDateTimeDest" name='arrivalDateTimeDest' value="<?php echo date('c', $row['arrivalDateTimeDest'])?>">
```

In light of the recent answers to this post, I've pinpointed the issue, however I cannot yet solve it. When input type = text, I have no issue echoing the value, however, I cannot do this when the input type is set to datetime-local.

Comment: what format you want to achieve?

Comment: what´s the format of `$row['arrivalDateTimeDest']`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually attempting to achieve a format of mm/dd/yyyy H:i:s

Comment: what does `echo $row['arrivalDateTimeDest']` show you?

Comment: For this particular value, when the input type is = to text, the value = 1990-12-08 13:13:00. However, when the input type is = datetime-local, the value = mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --. Problem is that I need the datetime-local input so that users can edit the value appropriately.

Comment: I posted an answer below, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strotitime before you change the format of date. Check below :

```
<?php $date = "2011-12-05 10:13 AM";?>
<input type='datetime-local' id="arrivalDateTimeDest" name='arrivalDateTimeDest' value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime($date)); ?>">
```

Comment: I attempted the above, however, I'm still ending up with a blank value

Comment: @aglowacki, I have updated my answer. Give it a try. I have added a function `strtotime` which will replace `-` separater of date to `/` as you have out in your format.

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there. Unfortunately, I'm still ending up with a blank

Comment: I changed `-` to `/` before you change the date format to Y/m/d

Comment: @aglowacki, one main change, change your input `type='text'`

Comment: I require the type=datetime-local so that users edit the value in an appropriate format.

Comment: Just make it `type="text"` just for once to make sure that it is the culprit.

Comment: I have done this, and the value does echo correctly when the type="text"

Comment: ok, @aglowacki I am about to get a solution for you. Be there.

Comment: @aglowacki, check my updated answer. I changed `value`. I tested with local and it worked well.

Comment: Himanshu Upadhyay you are an absolute life saver. This works magically! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your welcome. Happy to help. I like such challenging tasks. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes This is very simple task to do ,

1. Convert time from database to timestamp .

   `$timestamp = strtotime($row['arrivalDateTimeDest']);`
2. Then use date() function to format this date .. in a format which you want

   `echo date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);`

use this where you want to echo the date ... :) :)

Comment: @Code Lღver : Thanks I was not able to make it in code style :)

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` doesn't handle `mm/dd/yyyy` correctly, try this

`echo DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y H:i s", $row['arrivalDateTimeDest'])->format("y-m-d");`

so in your code it should look like this:

```
<input type='datetime-local' id="arrivalDateTimeDest" name='arrivalDateTimeDest' value="<?php echo DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y H:i:s", $row['arrivalDateTimeDest'])->format("y-m-d")?>">
```

make sure that this part: `"m/d/Y H:i s"` fits the format that you get from `$row['arrivalDateTimeDest']`

Comment: I have attempted this, however, it's not working appropriately. Could you post this including the input type, id, and name?